# The intersection part of CSS Canvas paths seem to have incorrect color.

Tags: html, css, canvas, web

I'm trying to draw a path using `HTML Canvas`. It consists of several Bezier curves linked together. For some reason, I cannot draw the whole path and then stroke. Instead, I need to stroke for each Bezier curve. I'm using a light purple color as the stroke color, but at the intersection of the curves, I seem to get something like white instead of the light purple I expect. Like this (sorry I can't post an image since I'm new on Stack Overflow):

[image: picture example]

I'm using `stroke style` with opacity 1, so I believe it's not a transparency issue. So what might be causing this problem?

FYI, I'm drawing each Bezier curve with code like this, where a is the drawing context of the canvas, and `this.bloom.c` is something like "`rgba(xxx,xxx,xxx,1)`":

```
a.strokeStyle = this.bloom.c;
a.beginPath();
a.moveTo(e.x, e.y);
a.bezierCurveTo(c.x, c.y, b.x, b.y, d.x, d.y);
a.stroke();
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: +1. Off the top of my head, the pixels are copied over one another in an RGBA additive fashion. PS: Putting your experiments on  http://jsfiddle.net will allow for quicker responses. From my experience Webkit and Chrome are the most reliable towards the canvas HTML5 implementation, so you won't see much difference here.

Comment: also see: Set blendmode for drawing strokes? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939453/set-blendmode-for-drawing-strokes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the appropriate "blend modes" natively supported by HTML5 Canvas context for Composite Operations. In your case you may use '`source-over`'

For [example](http://mrcoles.com/blog/canvas-composite-operations-demo-animation/):

```
var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
```

See [Compositing and Blending 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-compositing-20120816/)

```
source-atop
source-in
source-out
source-over
destination-atop
destination-in
destination-out
destination-over
lighter
xor
copy
```

Comment: Wow! It works like a charm! I did suspect it has something to do with blending mode but didn't know how to tweak that in HTML Canvas. Anyway really thank you a lot! Also I've got a screen shot of the whole picture of my site just in case you're curious what I'm going with~ [Picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b19wxsshsou7wea/Screen%20Shot%202012-09-23%20at%202.23.58%20AM.png)

Comment: @SundayLee Cheers! Consider adding another line e.g. `Result Update` to your post and showing us the result...